# How to stop Excel opening some sheets (downloaded via VBA) in new instance, causing PERSONAL.xlsb to invoke a "File in Use" dialog?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-erp

I run a lot of macros, and lately had to change to O365, which gave me the "wonderful" 64 bit Excel. One of its most maddening shenanigans is that when I run some macros (working with SAP GUI, creating SAP reports, naming them, saving and downloading to a specific folder where the next macro step opens them and incorporates into a relevant macro sheet), the **new Excel opens these in a new instance** (which I don't want but cannot prevent - *can you help here?*), which causes a dialog "File in Use" (which I don't want but cannot prevent - *can anyone help me here?*) because it tries to open my PERSONAL.XLSB (which I need and therefore don't want to get rid of just because of this) and qualifies it as "locked for editing" by another user, who is myself (which is absolutely stupid but I cannot change it - *can anyone help me perhaps with this part?*).

Sometimes the macro finishes fine when I don't answer that dialog; sometimes it seems to cause the Excel to hang up in trying to do next steps, sometimes the macro quits on me when I click "Read only" and so on.
All this is maddening also because **these files that (possibly) SAP GUI opens, I have to waste my time by closing them after the macro finishes** (*has anyone a possible solution in stopping SAP opening these files? I was unable to find it anywhere so far.*).

In some macros I fixed it by a specific part of code which waits till when these files open up and then it closes them - yet even that wait is wasting my time and it would be better without.
But with O365 and other instances it is even more colorful, because some files open in the same instance (this issue was there even before the O365 though) and I can manually close them after the macro finishes (although again, I have to wait till they open, which is again "vanity and torture of the soul"), but those opening in the new instance (specific to O365) show as blank sheets, I have to click into them, a warning sound follows but no dialog is visible, then I have to click into them again from the Excel icon in the bottom menu bar and then it tells me that I cannot close them because a dialog is open.
Then I need to close this dialog plus the one which appeared about the "File in Use", then I finally wait for the file (that I don't need) to open (because it is already saved inside the folder and already copied and pasted onto the relevant macro sheet) and only then I can close it.
So far **I was unable to find anywhere on the internet an advice for how to stop SAP opening these files** (when they are already saved where I need them), **neither how to stop them opening in new Excel instances.** So reluctantly, I think I should aim for **at least a tiny little VBA code which will cause my macro to click on the "Read Only" button**. **Can anyone here help me with any part of this "Excel complaint"?**

Comment: How do you open those files? By default, command `Workbooks.Open(filename)` opens each file in the same instance of Excel, unless you create an object before (Something like  `ExcelApp as Excel.Application`

Comment: It depends what SAP software, and what SAP reports you are talking about. Not all SAP programs work the same way. Some SAP applications start directly Excel asynchronously, it cannot be changed, and you need to close the Excel file yourself. NB: the software SAP GUI ultimately opens Excel files, but it's instructed by some other SAP programs or reports to do so. The choice of opening Excel depends on the SAP programs or reports, not SAP GUI.

Comment: Hello @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, both reports (FBL3N and one special report) are opened with this code:    'Copy/pasting the PUR11 data from the SAP export file to relevant sheet
    On Error Resume Next:
            Set WB = Workbooks(strfilenamexl): WB.Activate
            If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=fldrpath & strfilenamexl, ReadOnly:=True)
            If Not WB Is Nothing Then WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate Else MsgBox "File not found", vbInformation
            Err.Clear' So as you said, 'Workbooks.Open'

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how/if SAP can be 'persuaded' to not open the workbooks in discussion... But, I think, you can handle that in a different way the `"PERSONAL.XLSB"` behavior, from the opening point of view. Of course, **if SAP itself has this "bad habit" and not your code** opens it in a new session, which have to be solved in a different way...

1. `"PERSONAL.XLSB"` is located in "...AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART" folder. **All workbooks located in this folder are automatically open when an Excel session starts**;
2. You may change the `"PERSONAL.XLSB"` workbook path. If you want it to be open **when a specific (necessary) workbook needs it**, add a reference to it.

addRef. In order to do that, modify the (standard) VBAProject (of `"PERSONAL.XLSB"`), in, let us say, "VBPersProj", then (being in VBE) trough 'Tools - References...` tick its check box and press 'OK';

3. If the exported workbook is open in a new session and, even if it does not bother you any more because of the annoying dialogs and you need to identify that specific session, you can use the next function:

```
Function sameExSession(wbFullName As String, Optional boolClose As Boolean) As Boolean
   Dim sessEx As Excel.Application, wb As Workbook
  
   Set sessEx = GetObject(wbFullName).Application
   If sessEx.hWnd = Application.hWnd Then
        sameExSession = True
   Else
        sameExSession = False
        If boolClose Then
            sessEx.Workbooks(Right(wbFullName, Len(wbFullName) - InStrRev(wbFullName, "\"))).Close False
            sessEx.Quit: Set sessEx = Nothing
        End If
   End If
End Function
```

It offers the possibility to close the workbook and the session itself if it is a different against the one where the code runs. It is an `Optional` parameter to be used, only if you need that. You can test it in the next way:

```
Sub testSameExSession()
   Dim wbFullName As String
   wbFullName = ThisWorkbook.fullName 'use here the full name of the SAP exported workbook
   If sameExSession(wbFullName, True) Then
        'process the workbook if this is what you need        
   End If
   'if not open in the active session, the workbook could be closed and session quit, choosing the above way
   'You can also simply call the function, without the closing parameter, as:
   Debug.Print sameExSession(wbFullName)
End Sub
```

In case of `False` function retur, it can be closed and reopen in the existing session, if needed...

**Edited**:

If you need personal.xlsb being used/open when ribbon controls calls some of its Subs/functions, please adapt the code to call it in the next way:

```
Dim x as Long
x = Run("'C:\Users\your_UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!GiveMeFive", 4, 3)
```

if calling a function (with parameters), which must return. Or

```
Run "'C:\Users\your_UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!YourSubName"
```

when calling a `Sub`. In such a way, "Personal.xlsb" **is opened if it is closed**. And, in your specific case **nothing will press the ribbon controls**.

But, isn't the ribbon added when a specific workbook is open? Probably, the one you are using to make the above mentioned calls... If so, adding the suggested reference at "Personal.xlsb", will configure the new ribbon tab only when it is loaded. And your mentioned "problem" does not exist, in fact. Is it an add-in?

Comment: @Petr Hrubý Still alive...? Didn't you find some time to check the solution I posted, or received suggestion in the comment? If tested, didn't it solve your problem? When ask a question, it is at least polite to check it and send some feedback to the ones trying helping you...

Comment: Hey @FaneDuru, I need "Personal.xlsb" as I have some little macros on the ribbon, so it's not an option to rename it. Anyway thanks for your comments, but let me test it - today is not a day. :-)

Comment: @Petr Hrubý I did not suggested renaming it. I suggested moving it in a different folder than "XLSTART" folder! If you need it opening when use its macros from the ribbon controls, you must change the way of calling the sub. Please, try using, in fact, I will adapt the above answer. I have in mind some more code lines...